# HTML Parsing help to extract Author Names from URL website in R using getNodeSet

Tags: html, r, xml, parsing

I am having trouble extracting the names of authors as variables form the URL below in R. I understand the basics of the GetNodeSet when looking at the structure of data in xml format, but I don't believe I am using the right path or names in order to extract what I want.
Here is the step by step code of what I have done below.

```
mar16 <- getURL("https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-March/date.html", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
```

**My results**

```
<i>Jim Lemon
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437310.html">[R] size issue with source
</a><a name="437310">Â </a>
<i>Jun Chen
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437311.html">[R] Performance Analytics Modigliani Code help
</a><a name="437311">Â </a>
<i>Jessy-Esther Missengue
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437309.html">[R] rms package: output interpretation
</a><a name="437309">Â </a>
<i>T.Riedle
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437312.html">[R] Manually inserting an extra tick on the y axis in ggplot2
</a><a name="437312">Â </a>
<i>KMNanus
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437313.html">[R] How to add no data entries into current dataframe?
</a><a name="437313">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437314.html">[R] size issue with source
</a><a name="437314">Â </a>
<i>Boris Steipe
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437315.html">[R] rms package: output interpretation
</a><a name="437315">Â </a>
<i>David Winsemius
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437320.html">[R] Question about Imager
</a><a name="437320">Â </a>
<i>Jenny Vander Pluym - NOAA Federal
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437378.html">[R] [R-pkgs] New R package for K-S goodness-of-fit tests
</a><a name="437378">Â </a>
<i>Novack-Gottshall, Philip M.
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437316.html">[R] Persistent state in a function?
</a><a name="437316">Â </a>
<i>Boris Steipe
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437321.html">[R] converting a class dataframe (chars) to transaction class
</a><a name="437321">Â </a>
<i>Santanu Mukherjee
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437317.html">[R] Persistent state in a function?
</a><a name="437317">Â </a>
<i>Greg Snow
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437322.html">[R] fftImg() error: fftw_access_func
</a><a name="437322">Â </a>
<i>Eric Handler
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437318.html">[R] Manually inserting an extra tick on the y axis in ggplot2
</a><a name="437318">Â </a>
<i>John Kane
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437319.html">[R] [FORGED] Manually inserting an extra tick on the y axis in ggplot2
</a><a name="437319">Â </a>
<i>Rolf Turner
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437323.html">[R] Manually inserting an extra tick on the y axis in ggplot2
</a><a name="437323">Â </a>
<i>KMNanus
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437324.html">[R] Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...)
</a><a name="437324">Â </a>
<i>Mohamed Benahmed
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437325.html">[R] Question about Imager
</a><a name="437325">Â </a>
<i>Ben Tupper
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437329.html">[R] Coxph model treating all the values of 1 variable as separate variables PLEASE HELP!!
</a><a name="437329">Â </a>
<i>Shelby Leonard
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437326.html">[R] Logistic Regression output baseline (reference) category
</a><a name="437326">Â </a>
<i>Michael Artz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437327.html">[R] Logistic Regression output baseline (reference) category
</a><a name="437327">Â </a>
<i>David Winsemius
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437328.html">[R] fftImg() error: fftw_access_func
</a><a name="437328">Â </a>
<i>Uwe Ligges
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437330.html">[R] Coxph model treating all the values of 1 variable as separate variables PLEASE HELP!!
</a><a name="437330">Â </a>
<i>Marc Schwartz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437331.html">[R] Manually inserting an extra tick on the y axis in ggplot2
</a><a name="437331">Â </a>
<i>John Kane
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437332.html">[R] fftImg() error: fftw_access_func
</a><a name="437332">Â </a>
<i>John Kane
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437333.html">[R] fftImg() error: fftw_access_func
</a><a name="437333">Â </a>
<i>Shelby Leonard
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437334.html">[R] fftImg() error: fftw_access_func
</a><a name="437334">Â </a>
<i>David Winsemius
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437335.html">[R] help with function calls
</a><a name="437335">Â </a>
<i>Naresh Gurbuxani
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437336.html">[R] Open source project that needs performance optimizations
</a><a name="437336">Â </a>
<i>PSATHAS NILOS-HRISTOS
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437337.html">[R] Issue with var command in stats package
</a><a name="437337">Â </a>
<i>John, Larry
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437338.html">[R] Issue with var command in stats package
</a><a name="437338">Â </a>
<i>Sarah Goslee
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437339.html">[R] Issue with var command in stats package
</a><a name="437339">Â </a>
<i>David Winsemius
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437340.html">[R] Open source project that needs performance optimizations
</a><a name="437340">Â </a>
<i>Robert Sherry
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437341.html">[R] Robust ANCOVA
</a><a name="437341">Â </a>
<i>HAMID REZA ASHRAFI
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437342.html">[R] loading
</a><a name="437342">Â </a>
<i>farzana akbari
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437343.html">[R] loading
</a><a name="437343">Â </a>
<i>Uwe Ligges
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437344.html">[R] help with function calls
</a><a name="437344">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437345.html">[R] help with function calls
</a><a name="437345">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437346.html">[R] 'split-lapply' vs. 'aggregate'
</a><a name="437346">Â </a>
<i>Massimo Bressan
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437347.html">[R] 'split-lapply' vs. 'aggregate'
</a><a name="437347">Â </a>
<i>Fox, John
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437350.html">[R] How to form groups for this specific problem?
</a><a name="437350">Â </a>
<i>Satish Vadlamani
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437348.html">[R] Robust ANCOVA
</a><a name="437348">Â </a>
<i>Jim Lemon
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437349.html">[R] help with function calls
</a><a name="437349">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437351.html">[R] Robust ANCOVA
</a><a name="437351">Â </a>
<i>David Winsemius
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437352.html">[R] Robust ANCOVA
</a><a name="437352">Â </a>
<i>Martin Maechler
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437353.html">[R] Please guide -- UTF-8 locale setting fails on Windows on writing
</a><a name="437353">Â </a>
<i>Sunny Singha
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437354.html">[R] Please guide -- UTF-8 locale setting fails on Windows on writing
</a><a name="437354">Â </a>
<i>Milan Bouchet-Valat
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437355.html">[R] How to form groups for this specific problem?
</a><a name="437355">Â </a>
<i>Sarah Goslee
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437356.html">[R] Please guide -- UTF-8 locale setting fails on Windows on  writing
</a><a name="437356">Â </a>
<i>Sunny Singha
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437357.html">[R] How to form groups for this specific problem?
</a><a name="437357">Â </a>
<i>Adams, Jean
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437358.html">[R] Could not find function even though I have all necessary  packages
</a><a name="437358">Â </a>
<i>Michael Artz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437359.html">[R] Please guide -- UTF-8 locale setting fails on Windows on writing
</a><a name="437359">Â </a>
<i>Milan Bouchet-Valat
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437360.html">[R] Open source project that needs performance optimizations
</a><a name="437360">Â </a>
<i>Giorgio Garziano
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437361.html">[R] Could not find function even though I have all    necessary   packages
</a><a name="437361">Â </a>
<i>Jeff Newmiller
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437362.html">[R] Could not find function even though I have all necessary  packages
</a><a name="437362">Â </a>
<i>Michael Artz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437363.html">[R] Could not find function even though I have all necessary  packages
</a><a name="437363">Â </a>
<i>Michael Artz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437367.html">[R] How to form groups for this specific problem?
</a><a name="437367">Â </a>
<i>Satish Vadlamani
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437364.html">[R] Why missing values are not allowed in 'poly'?
</a><a name="437364">Â </a>
<i>William Dunlap
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437365.html">[R] Why missing values are not allowed in 'poly'?
</a><a name="437365">Â </a>
<i>Liviu Andronic
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437366.html">[R] help in maximum likelihood estimation
</a><a name="437366">Â </a>
<i>heba eldeeb
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437368.html">[R] [FORGED]  help in maximum likelihood estimation
</a><a name="437368">Â </a>
<i>Rolf Turner
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437369.html">[R] [FORGED] help in maximum likelihood estimation
</a><a name="437369">Â </a>
<i>William Dunlap
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437370.html">[R] Please guide -- UTF-8 locale setting fails on Windows on  writing
</a><a name="437370">Â </a>
<i>Sunny Singha
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437371.html">[R] how can I count data points outside the main plot line?
</a><a name="437371">Â </a>
<i>raz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437372.html">[R] how can I count data points outside the main plot line?
</a><a name="437372">Â </a>
<i>PIKAL Petr
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437373.html">[R] Performance Analytics Modigliani Code help
</a><a name="437373">Â </a>
<i>Jim Lemon
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437374.html">[R] how can I count data points outside the main plot line?
</a><a name="437374">Â </a>
<i>Giorgio Garziano
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437377.html">[R] How to solve an NLME problem?
</a><a name="437377">Â </a>
<i>David C Blouin
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437375.html">[R] How to form groups for this specific problem?
</a><a name="437375">Â </a>
<i>Adams, Jean
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437376.html">[R] converting a class dataframe (chars) to transaction class
</a><a name="437376">Â </a>
<i>Giorgio Garziano
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437379.html">[R] Can forecasting is possible through R Studio on the basis of past experience of data
</a><a name="437379">Â </a>
<i>Prasad Kale
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437380.html">[R] Can forecasting is possible through R Studio on the basis of past experience of data
</a><a name="437380">Â </a>
<i>Boris Steipe
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437381.html">[R] Can forecasting is possible through R Studio on the basis of past experience of data
</a><a name="437381">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437382.html">[R] Export the result k-means cluster to CSV file
</a><a name="437382">Â </a>
<i>S Ellison
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437383.html">[R] help in maximum likelihood estimation
</a><a name="437383">Â </a>
<i>Marc Girondot
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437384.html">[R] [FORGED]  help in maximum likelihood estimation
</a><a name="437384">Â </a>
<i>heba eldeeb
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437385.html">[R] R logo size in package information tab of Rstudio
</a><a name="437385">Â </a>
<i>Marc Girondot
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437386.html">[R] Total Least Squares Regression
</a><a name="437386">Â </a>
<i>Lorenzo Isella
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437387.html">[R] [FORGED]  help in maximum likelihood estimation
</a><a name="437387">Â </a>
<i>Jeff Newmiller
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437388.html">[R] How to solve an NLME problem?
</a><a name="437388">Â </a>
<i>Ben Bolker
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437390.html">[R] Convergence issues when using ns splines (pkg: spline) in Cox model (coxph) even when changing coxph.control
</a><a name="437390">Â </a>
<i>Jennifer Wu, Miss
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437389.html">[R] Accented characters, windows
</a><a name="437389">Â </a>
<i>Jan Kacaba
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437391.html">[R] R logo size in package information tab of Rstudio
</a><a name="437391">Â </a>
<i>Duncan Murdoch
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437392.html">[R] Accented characters, windows
</a><a name="437392">Â </a>
<i>Duncan Murdoch
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437394.html">[R] Filtering based on the occurrence
</a><a name="437394">Â </a>
<i>Farnoosh Sheikhi
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437393.html">[R] Compute the Gini coefficient
</a><a name="437393">Â </a>
<i>Marine Regis
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437395.html">[R] R logo size in package information tab of Rstudio
</a><a name="437395">Â </a>
<i>Marc Girondot
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437396.html">[R] R logo size in package information tab of Rstudio
</a><a name="437396">Â </a>
<i>Jeff Newmiller
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437411.html">[R] difficult to find index value
</a><a name="437411">Â </a>
<i>Rubel Das
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437397.html">[R] R logo size in package information
</a><a name="437397">Â </a>
<i>Marc Girondot
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437398.html">[R] how can I count data points outside the main plot line?
</a><a name="437398">Â </a>
<i>PIKAL Petr
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437399.html">[R] Filtering based on the occurrence
</a><a name="437399">Â </a>
<i>Jim Lemon
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437400.html">[R] Filtering based on the occurrence
</a><a name="437400">Â </a>
<i>Giorgio Garziano
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437401.html">[R] Convergence issues when using ns splines (pkg: spline) in Cox model (coxph) even when changing coxph.control
</a><a name="437401">Â </a>
<i>GÃ¶ran BrostrÃ¶m
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437402.html">[R] Compute the Gini coefficient
</a><a name="437402">Â </a>
<i>Erich Neuwirth
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437412.html">[R] Multinomial mixed models with glmmADMB
</a><a name="437412">Â </a>
<i>Ana MarÃ­a Prieto
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437403.html">[R] Compute the Gini coefficient
</a><a name="437403">Â </a>
<i>Achim Zeileis
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437413.html">[R] Problems with pooling Multiply Imuputed datasets, of a multilevel logistic model, using (MICE)
</a><a name="437413">Â </a>
<i>Jonathan Halls
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437404.html">[R] convergence issues with coxph
</a><a name="437404">Â </a>
<i>Therneau, Terry M., Ph.D.
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437414.html">[R] fftImg() error: fftw_access_func
</a><a name="437414">Â </a>
<i>Eric Handler
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437405.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437405">Â </a>
<i>Ryan Utz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437406.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437406">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437407.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437407">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437408.html">[R] installing packages
</a><a name="437408">Â </a>
<i>James Henson
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437409.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437409">Â </a>
<i>Joshua Ulrich
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437410.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437410">Â </a>
<i>Ryan Utz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437415.html">[R] R logo size in package information tab of Rstudio
</a><a name="437415">Â </a>
<i>Duncan Murdoch
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437416.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437416">Â </a>
<i>William Dunlap
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437417.html">[R] difficult to find index value
</a><a name="437417">Â </a>
<i>Ista Zahn
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437418.html">[R] Accented characters, windows
</a><a name="437418">Â </a>
<i>Jan Kacaba
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437419.html">[R]  Bagging Question
</a><a name="437419">Â </a>
<i>Majid Javanmard
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437420.html">[R] Convergence issues when using ns splines (pkg: spline) in Cox model (coxph) even when changing coxph.control
</a><a name="437420">Â </a>
<i>David Winsemius
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437421.html">[R] Boosting Algorithm for Regression (Adaboost.R2)
</a><a name="437421">Â </a>
<i>Majid Javanmard
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437422.html">[R] Boosting Algorithm for Regression (Adaboost.R2)
</a><a name="437422">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437423.html">[R] Convergence issues when using ns splines (pkg: spline) in Cox model (coxph) even when changing coxph.control
</a><a name="437423">Â </a>
<i>GÃ¶ran BrostrÃ¶m
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437425.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437425">Â </a>
<i>Norman Pat
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437424.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437424">Â </a>
<i>Ryan Utz
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437426.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437426">Â </a>
<i>David Winsemius
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437427.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437427">Â </a>
<i>Jordan Meyer
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437431.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437431">Â </a>
<i>Norman Pat
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437428.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437428">Â </a>
<i>Jim Lemon
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437429.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437429">Â </a>
<i>William Dunlap
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437432.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437432">Â </a>
<i>Norman Pat
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437430.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437430">Â </a>
<i>Jim Lemon
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437433.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437433">Â </a>
<i>David Winsemius
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437434.html">[R] R how to find outliers and zero mean columns?
</a><a name="437434">Â </a>
<i>Jim Lemon
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437435.html">[R] function to carry out Bootstrap LRT with poLCA results
</a><a name="437435">Â </a>
<i>Alain D.
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437436.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437436">Â </a>
<i>Giorgio Garziano
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437440.html">[R] Batch Installer for R
</a><a name="437440">Â </a>
<i>Tobias Knuth
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437437.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437437">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437438.html">[R] ts or xts with high-frequency data within a year
</a><a name="437438">Â </a>
<i>Bert Gunter
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437439.html">[R] Convergence issues when using ns splines (pkg: spline) in Cox model (coxph) even when changing coxph.control
</a><a name="437439">Â </a>
<i>Therneau, Terry M., Ph.D.
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437445.html">[R] Installing specific version of R
</a><a name="437445">Â </a>
<i>Sandhya Muloth Vijayachandran
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437441.html">[R] Batch Installer for R
</a><a name="437441">Â </a>
<i>Federman, Douglas
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437456.html">[R] is there any package for scienciometry
</a><a name="437456">Â </a>
<i>Fernando Roa
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437442.html">[R] Ask if an object will respond to a function or method
</a><a name="437442">Â </a>
<i>Paul Johnson
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437443.html">[R] converting a class dataframe (chars) to transaction class
</a><a name="437443">Â </a>
<i>Giorgio Garziano
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437444.html">[R] Ask if an object will respond to a function or method
</a><a name="437444">Â </a>
<i>Martin Morgan
</i>

</li>
<li>
<a href="437446.html">[R] reduced set of alternatives in package mlogit
</a><a name="437446">Â </a>
<i>Jose Marcos Ferraro
</i>

    </li>
</ul>
<p>
      <a name="end"><b>Last message date:</b></a> 
       <i>Thu Mar 31 23:51:15 CEST 2016</i><br><b>Archived on:</b> <i>Fri Apr  1 16:50:45 CEST 2016</i>
    </p>
<p>
   </p>
<ul>
<li> <b>Messages sorted by:</b>
            <a href="thread.html#start">[ thread ]</a>
        <a href="subject.html#start">[ subject ]</a>
        <a href="author.html#start">[ author ]</a>

         </li>
<li><b><a href="https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-help">More info on this list...
                    </a></b></li>
     </ul>
<p>
     </p>
<hr>
<i>This archive was generated by
     Pipermail 0.09 (Mailman edition).</i>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
unlist(getNodeSet(mar16parse,"/html/body/@a"), use.names=FALSE)
```

**My Results**

```
NULL
```

If you run the last line of code at the very bottom, your result is NULL.
Any suggestions on how to actually get the author names as a result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty straight forward request using the "rvest" package.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

#read web page
page<-read_html("https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-March/date.html")

#find the i tag below the li tag
author<-html_nodes(page, "li i") %>% html_text() %>% trimws()
```

Comment: So say I were to use the getNodeSet function instead, I would use "li" and "i" as my searching parameters? thanks

Comment: I find the XML package more difficult to use, but to answer your question yes the "/li/i" should be valid search path.

Comment: I find the XML package difficult too lol, your method is a lot more simple. Thanks for the help, I greatly appreciate it! One last thing just for future reference, would I also be able to use href, or name to specifically get the author's name you think?

Comment: In this case the names are enclosed within the "i" tag so that is where the names come from.  The css or xpath can be greatly expand to find whatever you need in the page.  For example, using something like `html_nodes(page, "li a[href]") %>% html_attr("href")` can return the html links.